# tensorflow import error in jupyter notebook in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning

1. I am writing a tensorflow program to find dogs vs cats prediction i got a error in this part of the code when i tried to execute this cell in juypter notebook.

2.Below is the code:

```
        import tflearn
        from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
        from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropoutfully_connected
        from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

        import tensorflow as tf
        tf.reset_default_graph()

       convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE,    1],name='input')

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')
```

----- -   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Error for the above code below (can anyone help to resolve this error):
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-2ef14dea0c38> in <module>()
    ----> 1 import tflearn
          2 from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
          3 from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
          4 from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
          5 

    /home/aravind/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py in <module>()
         19 
         20 # Predefined ops
    ---> 21 from .layers import normalization
         22 from . import metrics
         23 from . import activations

    /home/aravind/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/layers/__init__.py in <module>()
          8 from .normalization import batch_normalization, local_response_normalization
          9 from .estimator import regression
    ---> 10 from .recurrent import lstm, gru, simple_rnn, bidirectional_rnn, \
         11     BasicRNNCell, BasicLSTMCell, GRUCell
         12 from .embedding_ops import embedding

    /home/aravind/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/layers/recurrent.py in <module>()
          6 import tensorflow as tf
          7 from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
    ----> 8 from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn import static_rnn as _rnn, \
          9     static_bidirectional_rnn as _brnn
         10 from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn import rnn_cell_impl as _rnn_cell, \

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn'
```

Comment: Did you try to manually import tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn? If this does not work you might want to update tensorflow.

Comment: Thank u sir, i just updated the tensorflow in anaconda interperter and it worked.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz : Sir can u suggest good reading material and tutorials for opencv. If u have any knowledge on the subject kindly share the knowledge as i am also doing my project work in that field.can u give ur mail id so that i can contact u for my research as well.

Comment: For most things you might want to do using tensorflow scipy.misc should suffice. This means loading images / resizing them / cropping them. If you want to do more complex things like morphological operations, special filters and so on skimage should be enough. If you do want some special algorithms then just consult the opencv docs.